Why does the Beast wear eyeglasses?
Dr. Hank McCoy — a.k.a the Beast from the X-Men — wears eyeglasses, mainly for reading. However, according to the description of his superpowers (e.g. Marvel.com or Wikipedia), he has "animalistic" keen senses, including sharp eyesight. So why does he need to wear eyeglasses?
The out-of-universe answer is to make him look smart, as a gentle intellectual. But what is the in-universe answer?

It's probably worth noting that cats can't actually see very well up close (they use their whiskers for close range sensing) and Beast has something of a feline aspect. Probably not what the comic book authors were thinking of, but if it helps lampshade it in your mind...

"As the old English folk tale that has terrified children for aeons teaches us, all the better to see you with, my dear."

Beast is primarily seen wearing glasses when reading. Beast's Marvel Handbook entry states

Superhuman Senses: Hank possesses enhanced, acute senses that are comparable to those of certain animals, enabling him to see and hear distant objects more clearly than a normal human....

Therefore, it is possible that he wears them specifically because he is farsighted, so that he can see objects at a closer distance.

While it isn't mentioned in-universe, humans are presbyopic; we become farsighted with age and universally require reading glasses at some point. Depending on continuity, McCoy is usually old enough for this to affect him.

@Corbin - In the movies, sure, but in the Earth-616 comics, he's roughly the same age as the other original X-Men (Cyclops, Jean Grey, Angel and Iceman), and they were all teenagers when they debuted in the '60s. Over a decade has passed since then in-universe, but they can't be much older than 30.

@LogicDictates: That's old enough for aging to start. In their early 20s, three friends of mine went salt-and-pepper-haired, male-pattern bald, and presbyopic respectively. The latter friend has needed reading glasses since the age of about 24 or 25. Presbyopia is a plausible diagnosis, just not one supported explicitly by text.

@Corbin - The Beast has worn glasses since he was a teenager in the Earth-616 comics. The earliest example I've found is X-Men Vol. 1 #5 (May, 1964).

@FuzzyBoots - Are you sure the quote in your answer is genuinely from an official Marvel handbook? I checked Hank's entries in five different editions, and don't see the quoted text in any of them.

@LogicDictates: Truthfully, no. I ran into a quote online that said it was from the Marvel Handbook, and I believed them.

When I google that quote, the only matches I get are this thread, a Reddit post, and several fan wikis, such as this one. I'm guessing that one of the fan wikis is the original source.

According to the Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Master Edition #14, the Beast is nearsighted and requires reading glasses.


Special limitations: Nearsighted, requires reading glasses

Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Master Edition #14 (January, 1992)

Presumably, whoever wrote that entry meant to say that he's farsighted rather than nearsighted, if he requires reading glasses.
And apparently he does require reading glasses, since he stated that he couldn't read the text on a computer screen without them.

BEAST: Actually, I was wondering where my glasses were--I can't read a thing on this screen without them.

X-Men Vol. 2 #24 (September, 1993)

Note that while his Marvel.com and Wikipedia pages do state that he has heightened/superhuman senses, they don't say anything about him having sharp eyesight.
His Marvel Database page does state that he can see distant objects more clearly than a normal human, however, this is an unofficial bio and no citation is given for that claim, so it should be taken with a pinch of salt. Also, even if that claim is true, it wouldn't contradict him being farsighted and having poor vision at close range.

Superhuman Senses: Hank possesses enhanced, acute senses that are comparable to those of certain animals, enabling him to see and hear distant objects more clearly than a normal human, and identify and track someone purely by scent over open terrain and his hands and feet are sensitive enough to detect electronic signals (from bombs, listening devices, etc.) through solid walls and floors. He also possesses cat-like night-vision that also allows him to see even in near-total darkness and when asked by Nick Fury, he was able to identify that it was the real Colossus when he came back to life all by scent.
Marvel Database page for Henry McCoy (Earth-616)

I checked several of his earlier and later Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe entries, and the one I quoted at the top of this answer is the only one I found that touches on him being near/farsighted. His earlier entries don't mention his senses at all. Later entries state that he has enhanced senses, but the only vision-related enhancement specified is cat-like night vision.

The Beast has enhanced senses, can secrete pheromones to attract members of the opposite sex, and has a healing factor that allows him to regenerate from minor wounds and quickly recover from minor ailments such as colds. The Beast also possesses cat-like night vision, as well as razor-sharp claws on his hands and feet.

Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #1 (March, 2008)

